# proving strong induction in coq from scratch

Tags: coq, induction

I am in the middle of proving the equivalence of weak and strong induction.

I have a definition like:

```
Definition strong_induct (nP : nat->Prop) : Prop :=
  nP 0 /\
  (forall n : nat,
    (forall k : nat, k <= n -> nP k) ->
    nP (S n))
.
```

And I would like to prove the following, and wrote:

```
Lemma n_le_m__Sn_le_Sm : forall n m,
  n <= m -> S n <= S m
.
```

```
Lemma strong_induct_nP__nP_n__nP_k : forall (nP : nat->Prop)(n : nat),
  strong_induct nP -> nP n ->
  (forall k, k < n -> nP k)
.
Proof.
  intros nP n [Hl Hr].
  induction n as [|n' IHn].
  - intros H k H'. inversion H'.
  - intros H k H'.
    inversion H'.
    + destruct n' as [|n''] eqn : En'.
      * apply Hl.
      * apply Hr.
        unfold lt in IHn.
        assert(H'' : nP (S n'') -> forall k : nat, k <= n'' -> nP k). {
          intros Hx kx Hxx.
          apply n_le_m__Sn_le_Sm in Hxx.
          apply IHn.
          - apply Hx.
          - apply Hxx.
        }
```

However I cannot continue the proof any further.
How can I prove the lemma in this situation?

Comment: There's a problem in the statement you are trying to prove. `strong_induct nP` is always true, independently of `nP`. So the lemma really says `nP n -> forall k, k < n -> nP k` which is untrue.

Comment: I don't understand what the lemma you are trying to prove has to do with proving equivalence between weak and strong induction. Are you having trouble showing that strong induction implies weak induction or the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the place of `forall` in the main lemma makes it much easier to prove. I wrote it as follow:

```
Lemma strong_induct_is_correct : forall (nP : nat->Prop),
  strong_induct nP -> (forall n k, k <= n -> nP k).
```

(Also note that in the definition of `strong_induct` you used `<=` so it's better to use the same relation in the lemma as I did.)

So I could use the following lemma:

```
Lemma leq_implies_le_or_eq: forall m n : nat,
  m <= S n -> m <= n \/ m = S n.
```

to prove the main lemma like this:

```
Proof.
  intros nP [Hl Hr] n.
  induction n as [|n' IHn].
  - intros k Hk. inversion Hk. apply Hl.
  - intros k Hk. apply leq_implies_le_or_eq in Hk.
    destruct Hk as [Hkle | Hkeq].
    + apply IHn. apply Hkle.
    + rewrite Hkeq. apply Hr in IHn. apply IHn.
Qed.
```

This is much a simpler proof and also you can prove a prettier lemma using the lemma above.

```
Lemma strong_induct_is_correct_prettier : forall (nP : nat->Prop),
  strong_induct nP -> (forall n, nP n).
Proof.
  intros nP H n.
  apply (strong_induct_is_correct nP H n n).
  auto.
Qed.
```

**Note:** Usually after using a `destruct` or `induction` tactic once, it is not very helpful to use one of them again. So I think using `destruct n'` after `induction n` would not bring you any further.